# R Data.table filtering rows based a vector of columns greater than value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a variable list of column names in a data.table, and would like to apply the same filter to all of them to subset the rows of my table (i.e. give me the rows where all the columns in the list are >= 5)

```
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 1:6,
  b = 7:12,
  c = 13:18
)
> DT
   ID a  b  c
1:  b 1  7 13
2:  b 2  8 14
3:  b 3  9 15
4:  a 4 10 16
5:  a 5 11 17
6:  c 6 12 18

cols= c("a", "b", "c")
DT[.SD >= 5, , .SDcols=cols] # something like this?
   ID a  b  c
1:  a 5 11 17
2:  c 6 12 18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need to have the conditions met for all the columns, create a `list` of logical vectors and then `Reduce` it to a single logical vector

```
DT[DT[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `>=`, 5)), .SDcols = cols]]
#   ID a  b  c
#1:  a 5 11 17
#2:  c 6 12 18
```

---

Or another option with `rowSums`

```
DT[ DT[, rowSums(.SD >= 5) == length(cols), .SDcols = cols]]
```

NOTE: Both options are vectorized and are efficient

#### Benchmarks

```
DT1 <- DT[rep(seq_len(nrow(DT)), 1e6)]



system.time(DT1[ DT1[, rowSums(.SD >= 5) == length(cols), .SDcols = cols]])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.464   0.127   0.555 

system.time(DT1[DT1[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `>=`, 5)), .SDcols = cols]])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.134   0.022   0.150 



system.time(DT1[ DT1[, apply(.SD >= 5, 1, all), .SDcols=cols], ])
#     user  system elapsed 
#  6.636   0.087   6.687
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DT[ DT[, apply(.SD >= 5, 1, all), .SDcols=cols], ]
#    ID a  b  c
# 1:  a 5 11 17
# 2:  c 6 12 18
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `.SDcols = is.numeric` if you were looking at all the numeric columns. This saves one step.